# How to update/remove object in array based on condition in JS?

Tags: javascript

I have the below query in nodejs and if the user pass skip and limit value. I have to update it else I have to remove those from the query

```
[
    {
        "$match": {"PaymentStatus" : "Submitted"}
    },
    {
        "$sort": {
            "Date": -1
        }
    },
    {
         "$skip": "$skip"
    }, 
    {
        "$limit": "$limit"
    },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "bookings",
            "localField": "_id",
            "foreignField": "",
            "as": "bookings"
        }
    },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "users",
            "localField": "bookings.user_id",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "User"
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "Number": "$Number",
            "Status": "$bookings.Status",
            "User": "$bookings.AssignedTo",
            "VendorName": "$booking.username",
            "SystemID": "$booking._id"
        }
    }
]
```

if (skip && limit)// skip 100 and limit 300

query(output) should be

```
[
    {
        "$match": {"PaymentStatus" : "Submitted"}
    },
    {
        "$sort": {
            "Date": -1
        }
    },
    {
         "$skip": 100
    }, 
    {
        "$limit": 300
    },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "bookings",
            "localField": "_id",
            "foreignField": "",
            "as": "bookings"
        }
    },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "users",
            "localField": "bookings.user_id",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "User"
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "Number": "$Number",
            "Status": "$bookings.Status",
            "User": "$bookings.AssignedTo",
            "VendorName": "$booking.username",
            "SystemID": "$booking._id"
        }
    }
]
```

else we have to remove these two items from query

```
[
    {
        "$match": {"PaymentStatus" : "Submitted"}
    },
    {
        "$sort": {
            "Date": -1
        }
    },
    
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "bookings",
            "localField": "_id",
            "foreignField": "",
            "as": "bookings"
        }
    },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "users",
            "localField": "bookings.user_id",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "User"
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "Number": "$Number",
            "Status": "$bookings.Status",
            "User": "$bookings.AssignedTo",
            "VendorName": "$booking.username",
            "SystemID": "$booking._id"
        }
    }
]
```

How can we do this? please help me with this. are these the correct approaches?
working codes are below but need advise

Below is my code to remove items from the query.

```
var myArray = query.filter(function( obj ) {
    return obj.$skip !== '$skip'&& obj.$limit !== '$limit'
});
```

also, update query is below

```
var a = 100 ;
var b = 300;
const newArr = query.map(obj => {
  if (obj.$skip=== '$skip') {
    return {...obj, $skip: a};
  }
  if (obj.$limit=== '$limit') {
    return {...obj, $limit: b};
  }
  return obj;
});
console.log(newArr)
```

Comment: why your $skip is not in inverted commas? any specific reason behind it?

Comment: Because it’s a dynamic value so keep it like that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update query based on skip and limit you can push that fields based on condition as -

```
const query = [
    {
        "$match": {"PaymentStatus" : "Submitted"}
    },
    {
        "$sort": {
            "Date": -1
        }
    },
    
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "bookings",
            "localField": "_id",
            "foreignField": "",
            "as": "bookings"
        }
    },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "users",
            "localField": "bookings.user_id",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "User"
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "Number": "$Number",
            "Status": "$bookings.Status",
            "User": "$bookings.AssignedTo",
            "VendorName": "$booking.username",
            "SystemID": "$booking._id"
        }
    }
]
```

and push data as:-

```
if (skip && limit) {
    query.splice(2, 0, {
         "$limit": limit
     })
    query.splice(2, 0, {
         "$skip": skip
     })
    }
```

it should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

as I understood you want to remove `skip` and/or `limit` objects from array if value is not defined, you can filter this array

```
var myArray = query.filter(function( obj ) {
    if ('$skip' in obj && !obj.$skip) {
       return false;
    }
    if ('$limit' in obj && !obj.$limit) {
       return false;
    }

    return true;
});
```